# Keras LSTM: how to predict beyond validation vs predictions?

Tags: tensorflow, machine-learning, keras, time-series, lstm

When dealing with time series forecasting, I've seen most people follow these steps when using an LSTM model:

1. Obtain, clean, and pre-process data
2. Take out validation dataset for future comparison with model predictions
3. Initialise and train LSTM model
4. Use a copy of validation dataset to be pre-processed exactly like the training data
5. Use trained model to make predictions on the transformed validation data
6. Evaluate results: predictions vs validation

However, if the model is accurate, how do you make predictions that go beyond the end of the validation period?

The following only accepts data that have been transformed in the same way as the training data, but for predictions that go beyond the validation period, you don't have any input data to feed to the model. So, how do people do this?

```
# Predictions vs validation
predictions = model.predict(transformed_validation)

# Future predictions
future_predictions = model.predict(?)
```

[image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To predict the ith value, your LSTM model need last N values.
So if you want to forecast, you should use each prediction to predict the next one.

In other terms you have to loop over something like

```
prediction = model.predict(X[-N:])
X.append(prediction)
```

As you can guess, you add your output in your input that's why your predictions can diverge and amplify uncertainty.

Other model are more stable to predict far future.

Comment: Nice one Harold!!

Comment: And what is the difference between forecasting 3 values for example and doing multistep of three values? I cannot find clear information about this topic

Comment: @bardulia hi! have you got more information about this? I'm also struggling on the same question.

Comment: @Firate unfortunately I haven't. But at least it is good to see that other people have the same issue. If I find something, I will post an answer.

Answer (score -2):

You have to break your data into training and testing and then fit your mode. Finally, you make a prediction like this.

```
future_predictions = model.predict(X_test)
```

Check out the link below for all details.

[Time-Series Forecasting: Predicting Stock Prices Using An LSTM Model](https://towardsdatascience.com/lstm-time-series-forecasting-predicting-stock-prices-using-an-lstm-model-6223e9644a2f)

Comment: This is not predicting future values, but only predicting the values to be compared to the holdout dataset. As a data scientist, you already have these values. I'm talking about further into the future, for which you don't have any data.

Comment: Sorry, but I don't know about that. Hopefully someone else will jump in here and contribute a solution that meets your expectations.